# Как закрепить tablerow?

Tags: android

Подскажите, есть ли возможность закрепить верхнюю и нижнюю строки отображаемой таблицы? т.е. может как-то организовать прокрутку внутри `TableLayout` без использования `ScrollView`

Comment: Прокрутка без ScrollView ее получится. Уточните чего вы хотите добиться, что значит закрепить строку?

Comment: @lllyct есть таблица. надо чтоб верхняя и нижняя строка всегда отображались (не прокручивались). Строки между ними - да, прокручиваются.

Comment: Так не получится. Чтобы что-то прокручивалось нужен один из специальных контейреров. Внутрь TableLayout с сохранением самой таблицы его никак не сложить.

Comment: Я тут вижу только 1 вариант: надо обернуть TableLayout в ScrollView, а вокруг ScrollView добавить не скролящиеся элементы. Но для синхронизации разбиения по столбцам в не скролящихся элементах придется писать какой-то страшный код в java. Но если размеры столбцов фиксированные, то проблем быть не должно.

Comment: @lllyct спасибо! тоже про это думаю... проблема как раз в том, что не хочется привязываться к ширине столбцов...

Comment: задавая вопрос, надеялся, что может кто-нить подскажет виджет какой готовый. т.к. задача, по-моему, достаточно типовая....